# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - but it is?

Tags: asp.net, class

I am creating a Sudoku Puzzle in asp and I'm having trouble with some classes. When I create a function to display all the numbers in the text box, I get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I know that it means that my object is null, but here is my code. The line that I am getting the error on is the line that says: stbNumber.setNumber(currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n]);

```
private SudokuTextBox stb;
private Puzzle puzzle;
private Box box;
private Number stbNumber;


public void displayAll(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    puzzle = new Puzzle();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            box = new Box();
            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                {
                    stbNumber = new Number();
                    stb = new SudokuTextBox();
                    stbNumber.setNumber(currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n]);
                    stb.setTextBoxValue(stbNumber);
                    stb.setVisibility(true);
                    box.setItem(stb, m, n);
                }// end forth for
            }//end third for
            puzzle.setItem(box, i, k);
        }//end second for
    }//end first for
    generateBoxes();
}
```

I have initialized stbNumber at the very top of my code, and I have made sure that currentSolution is not null or empty. I'm therefore unsure as to what I am doing wrong. I also should mention that I have this exact code elsewhere to generate new puzzles and it works just fine, but this section of code specifically gets called when I click a button.

Comment: Can you post the code where you make sure the currentSolution is not null?

Answer (score 0):

you essentially have 3 possibilities:

```
stbNumber.setNumber(currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n]);
```

`stbNumber` could be null

`currentSolution` could be null

the element you are trying to index could be null--just because currentSolution is not null does not mean the item is at that index is not null--so new one up or take appropriate action

since you new up an instance of `stbNumber`, it is unlikely to be the culprit (but it could be)
you say you are checking currentSolution is null, I don't see the code for that and from the code you did post it is most likely the culprit here.  what you COULD do is add a check for null before you access it, and if your test fails writing an error message somewhere:

```
    stbNumber = new Number();
    stb = new SudokuTextBox();
    if ( currentSolution != null )
    {
       // if the item does not exist, new it up
       if ( currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n] == null ) currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n] = new someObject()
       stbNumber.setNumber(currentSolution[3 * i + m, 3 * k + n]);
       stb.setTextBoxValue(stbNumber);
    }
    else
    {
      WriteSomeErrorMessage("currentSolution is null");
    }
```

Comment: I found out what the culprit is. I call a class called puzzle in the first page load of my code (not in the post back). Yet, when I click on the button that uses this code, it makes it seem as if the puzzle object is null.

Comment: The first code that posted is a function that gets called when the page loads, and this is the code that is called when the button is pressed.

Comment: {
        box = new Box();
        stb = new SudokuTextBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                box = puzzle.getItem(i, k);

                for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                    {
                        stb = box.getItem(m, n);
                        stb.setVisibility(true);
                    }// end forth for
                }//end third for
            }//end second for
        }//end first for
    }